# How can I skip some setup for specific Rspec tags?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Rspec makes it easy to configure setup based on the **presence** of test tags. For example, if some tests need a parallel universe to be created (assuming you have code to do that):

```
# some_spec.rb
describe "in a parallel universe", alter_spacetime: true do
  # whatever
end

# spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, :alter_spacetime) do |example|
    # fancy magic here
  end
end
```

But I want to do the opposite: "before each test, **unless you see this tag**, do the following..."

How can I skip a setup step in `spec_helper` based on the presence of a tag on some tests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first, you would expect something like

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, alter_spacetime: false) do |example|
    # fancy magic here
  end
end
```

to work that way, but it doesn't.

But you have access to `example`, which is an [Example](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Example) instance and has the `#metadata` method, which returns [Metadata](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Metadata) object. You can check the value of the flag with that, and a flag on the specific example will override one on the containing `describe` block.

```
config.before(:each) do |example|
  # Note that we're not using a block param to get `example`
  unless example.metadata[:alter_spacetime] == false
    # fancy magic here
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmmm. With this setting, I'd expect existing, untagged specs to do the setup. But they don't. They have to be tagged `alter_spacetime: false` to do it. `before(:each, alter_spacetime: nil)` is the same.

Comment: @NathanLong thank you for feedback - looked deeper and updated question. This variant is not so fancy, but should work. Let's hope, there is more elegant way to do that. =)

Comment: I edited your answer after some tinkering, but this works well for me and I think is elegant enough. Thanks! :)